# Why am I getting a value error on a 2 Valued tuple receiving 2 values in this neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network

I have been studying neural networks for some time, and I have decided to work with Michael Neilsen's book "Neural Networks and Deep Learning".
The book has been very good and it passed the concept of neural networks perfectly.
But,
While practicing the material taught I had encountered an error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

I have tried debugging, converting tuples to lists, running the program in Python 3.9 and Python 2.7, rewriting the whole program, copying it as a whole from github, running through different IDEs, and nothing changed the error.

The network file is as such :

```
import numpy as np
import mnist_loader
import random

class Network(object):
    def __init__(self,sizes):
        # eg. Network([2,3,1]) makes an array of arrays, in this eg. a 2 input,3 hidden, 1 output neural network
        self.num_layers = len(sizes)
        self.sizes = sizes
        #All weights and biases are initialised randomly in gaussian normal distribution, and are initialised in sizes 1 an on(1st hidden layer to output)
        self.biases = [np.random.randn(y,1)
                       for y in sizes[1:]] #[1:] means
        self.weights =[np.random.randn(y,x)
                       for x,y in zip(sizes[:-1],sizes[1:])]

    def feedforward(self,a):
            """Return the output of the network if "a" is input."""
            for b,w in zip(self.biases,self.weights):
                a = sigmoid(np.dot(w,a)+b)
            return a

    def SGD(self,training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size,eta,test_data=None): #eta - learning rate,test_data=None initialises empty var
            """Train the neural network using mini-batch stochastic
                    gradient descent.  The "training_data" is a list of tuples
                    "(x, y)" representing the training inputs and the desired
                    outputs.  The other non-optional parameters are
                    self-explanatory.  If "test_data" is provided then the
                    network will be evaluated against the test data after each
                    epoch, and partial progress printed out.  This is useful for
                    tracking progress, but slows things down substantially."""
            if test_data: n_test = len(test_data) #If test_data carries value, make n_test in length of test_data
            n= len(training_data)
            for j in range(epochs):
                random.shuffle(training_data)
                mini_batches = [training_data[k:k+mini_batch_size]
                                for k in range(0,n,mini_batch_size)]
            for mini_batch in mini_batches:
                self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch,eta)
            if test_data:
                print("Epoch {0}: {1} /{2}".format(
                    j,self.evaluate(test_data),n_test))
            else:
                print ("Epoch {0} complete".format(j))
    def update_mini_batch(self , mini_batch,eta):
            """Update the network's weights and biases by applying
                    gradient descent using backpropagation to a single mini batch.
                    The "mini_batch" is a list of tuples "(x, y)", and "eta"
                    is the learning rate."""
            # nabla = gradient vector np.zeros makes b into an array of zeros the size of self.biases
            nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
            nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
            for x, y in mini_batch:
                delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backprop(x, y)
                nabla_b = [nb + dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
                nabla_w = [nw + dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]

            self.weights = [w - (eta / len(mini_batch)) * nw for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
            self.biases = [b - (eta / len(mini_batch)) * nb for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]

    def backprop(self, x, y):
            """Return a tuple ``(nabla_b, nabla_w)`` representing the
            gradient for the cost function C_x.  ``nabla_b`` and
            ``nabla_w`` are layer-by-layer lists of numpy arrays, similar
            to ``self.biases`` and ``self.weights``."""
            nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
            nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
            # feedforward
            activation = x
            activations = [x]  # list to store all the activations, layer by layer
            zs = []  # list to store all the z vectors, layer by layer
            for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
                z = np.dot(w, activation) + b
                zs.append(z)
                activation = sigmoid(z)
                activations.append(activation)
            # backward pass
            delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * \
                    sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])
            nabla_b[-1] = delta
            nabla_w[-1] = np.dot(delta, activations[-2].transpose())
            # Note that the variable l in the loop below is used a little
            # differently to the notation in Chapter 2 of the book.  Here,
            # l = 1 means the last layer of neurons, l = 2 is the
            # second-last layer, and so on.  It's a renumbering of the
            # scheme in the book, used here to take advantage of the fact
            # that Python can use negative indices in lists.
            for l in range(2, self.num_layers):
                z = zs[-l]
                sp = sigmoid_prime(z)
                delta = np.dot(self.weights[-l + 1].transpose(), delta) * sp
                nabla_b[-l] = delta
                nabla_w[-l] = np.dot(delta, activations[-l - 1].transpose())
            return (nabla_b, nabla_w)

    def evaluate(self, test_data):
            """Return the number of test inputs for which the neural
            network outputs the correct result. Note that the neural
            network's output is assumed to be the index of whichever
            neuron in the final layer has the highest activation."""
            test_results = [(np.argmax(self.feedforward(x)), y)
                            for (x, y) in test_data]
            return sum(int(x == y) for (x, y) in test_results)

    def cost_derivative(self, output_activations, y):
            """Return the vector of partial derivatives \partial C_x /
            \partial a for the output activations."""
            return (output_activations - y)

def sigmoid(z):
    """The sigmoid function."""
    return 1.0/(1-np.np.exp(-z))

def sigmoid_prime(z):
    """Derivative of the sigmoid function."""
    return sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))
```

The dataset arrangement is as such:

```
# Standard library
import _pickle as cPickle
import gzip

# Third-party libraries
import numpy as np

def load_data():
    """Return the MNIST data as a tuple containing the training data,
    the validation data, and the test data.

    The ``training_data`` is returned as a tuple with two entries.
    The first entry contains the actual training images.  This is a
    numpy ndarray with 50,000 entries.  Each entry is, in turn, a
    numpy ndarray with 784 values, representing the 28 * 28 = 784
    pixels in a single MNIST image.

    The second entry in the ``training_data`` tuple is a numpy ndarray
    containing 50,000 entries.  Those entries are just the digit
    values (0...9) for the corresponding images contained in the first
    entry of the tuple.

    The ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are similar, except
    each contains only 10,000 images.

    This is a nice data format, but for use in neural networks it's
    helpful to modify the format of the ``training_data`` a little.
    That's done in the wrapper function ``load_data_wrapper()``, see
    below.
    """
    f = gzip.open("G:\Datasets/beural-networks-and-deep-learning-master/beural-networks-and-deep-learning-master\data\mnist.pkl.gz", 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = cPickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def load_data_wrapper():
    """Return a tuple containing ``(training_data, validation_data,
    test_data)``. Based on ``load_data``, but the format is more
    convenient for use in our implementation of neural networks.

    In particular, ``training_data`` is a list containing 50,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  ``x`` is a 784-dimensional numpy.ndarray
    containing the input image.  ``y`` is a 10-dimensional
    numpy.ndarray representing the unit vector corresponding to the
    correct digit for ``x``.

    ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are lists containing 10,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  In each case, ``x`` is a 784-dimensional
    numpy.ndarry containing the input image, and ``y`` is the
    corresponding classification, i.e., the digit values (integers)
    corresponding to ``x``.

    Obviously, this means we're using slightly different formats for
    the training data and the validation / test data.  These formats
    turn out to be the most convenient for use in our neural network
    code."""
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    training_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
    training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
    training_data = zip(training_inputs, training_results)
    validation_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in va_d[0]]
    validation_data = zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1])
    test_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in te_d[0]]
    test_data = zip(test_inputs, te_d[1])
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def vectorized_result(j):
    """Return a 10-dimensional unit vector with a 1.0 in the jth
    position and zeroes elsewhere.  This is used to convert a digit
    (0...9) into a corresponding desired output from the neural
    network."""
    e = np.zeros((10, 1))
    e[j] = 1.0
    return e
```

and the training commands are as such:

```
import network
import mnist_loader

training_data , validation_data, test_data = mnist_loader.load_data()
training_data = list(training_data) 

net = network.Network([784,30,10])
net.SGD(training_data, 30, 10, 0.001, test_data=test_data)
```

Comment: What's the full traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
--------
  File "...\train.py", line 8, in <module>
    net.SGD(training_data, 30, 10, 0.001, test_data=test_data)
--------
  File "...\network.py", line 40, in SGD
    self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch,eta)
-----
  File "...network.py", line 55, in update_mini_batch
    for x, y in mini_batch:
-----
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: I get an error when I try to run your data, maybe it's something from my side. But the error is clear. Check what shape `mini_batch` has just before line 55 in network.py and work backwards by figuring out why `Network.SGD` calls `update_mini_batch` with the wrong array shape. What shape is `training_data`?

Comment: I tried assigning training data as a  tuple and a list, as a list I got a TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment, and as a list I got the error mentioned above.

Comment: I tried assigning training data as a  tuple and a list, as a list I got a TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment, and as a list, I got the error mentioned above.
I checked the mini_batch length, and it containing two arrays as expected, which I assumed would fit the x,y variables in the for loop.
Changing the  amount of index variable gave a similar error, in e.g: giving x,y,z vars gave me :
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3).

Answer (score 0):

So, the code had a few bugs I had to settle.
There was a typeError because I was using the data without wrapping it properly.
First of all was using the load_data function instead of the load_data_wrapper, which just gave out a total mess, second of all, In load_data_wrapper, I needed to change the "zip"
format commands to "list" as such:

'''

```
def load_data_wrapper():
    """Return a tuple containing ``(training_data, validation_data,
    test_data)``. Based on ``load_data``, but the format is more
    convenient for use in our implementation of neural networks.

    In particular, ``training_data`` is a list containing 50,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  ``x`` is a 784-dimensional numpy.ndarray
    containing the input image.  ``y`` is a 10-dimensional
    numpy.ndarray representing the unit vector corresponding to the
    correct digit for ``x``.

    ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are lists containing 10,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  In each case, ``x`` is a 784-dimensional
    numpy.ndarry containing the input image, and ``y`` is the
    corresponding classification, i.e., the digit values (integers)
    corresponding to ``x``.

    Obviously, this means we're using slightly different formats for
    the training data and the validation / test data.  These formats
    turn out to be the most convenient for use in our neural network
    code."""
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    training_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
    training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
    training_data = list(zip(training_inputs, training_results))
    validation_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in va_d[0]]
    validation_data = list(zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1]))
    test_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in te_d[0]]
    test_data = list(zip(test_inputs, te_d[1]))
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)
```

'''

And last but not least, the sigmoid function was wrong, and made an overflow because of a simple '-/+' mistake. Should look like this:

'''

```
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z))
```

'''

After applying all fixes, the code should work perfectly.

Special thanks to the contributors at https://github.com/nndl-solutions/NNDL-solutions